# what happens if I drive without coolant?

Tags: honda, coolant, cooling-system, fit

My car is a Honda fit 2009 and the coolant is low, should I just buy coolant? or is it something more serious?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes overtime cars use a small amount of coolant. The first thing you should do is buy coolant and top off and then keep watching it over the next few days and weeks to see if the level goes down quickly or not.

Answer (score 1):

In my 1999 Camry I had a crack in the radiator, which meant coolant would spray out all over my engine bay.  If your coolant is low that can be a sign of a leak.  Try parking with your car over some newspaper or white towels for a night to see if anything is leaking.